# How to get selected value in drop down in angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application there is a drop down(combo box) am populating drop down value 
using json array object.can anybody tell how to get selected value from drop down in angular js controller

Thanks

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ng-options and ng-model.  Your HTML will look something like this:

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
```

reference:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions